# Import JSON file to mongos

Tags: json, mongodb, sharding, mongoimport

I am simulating sharding in MongoDB. The sharded cluster has been configured and I have three shards on three different physical machines connected over a network.

shard1 , shard 2, shard 3

I connected to a mongos and created a database, a collection and enabled sharding on the created database.

Now I need to insert a large dataset so I can shard the collection.
I am using `mongoimport` as below.
[image: command line]

My problem is that this dataset is being imported to the local database on the host machine. E.g. if I connect a mongo shell to a mongod I can see that the new database has XX.GB but I am connect to a config server with a mongos but when I run `show dbs` on the mongos I see 00.GB in the created database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to issue `mongoimport` against the `mongos` instance via the [--host](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--host) parameter so that the routing service can appropriately distribute the data to the shards

Comment: Because I have read that mongoimport can is not intended to run when connected with a mongo or mongos

Comment: You mentioned you have a sharded cluster so you have to have a `mongos` instance running which reads from the config instances to know how to shard your collection - and to this `mongos` you have to point your `mongoimport` cmdline via `--host` and the appropriate IP / dns name and port

Comment: @user2307236 i have given the full example in detail .. let me know if u still have any questions

Answer (score 4):

Imagine your sharded environment something like below. with 3 shards and each shard has 3 servers.

```
   shards:
            {  "_id" : "s0",  "host" : "s0/localhost:37017,localhost:37018,localhost:37019" }
            {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "s1/localhost:47018,localhost:47019" }
            {  "_id" : "s2",  "host" : "s2/localhost:57017,localhost:57018,localhost:57019" }
      active mongoses:
            "3.2.5" : 1
```

Now to import a json to a sharded environment follow the below steps.

1. Connect to any of the sharded instances via mongos.
   mongo --port 47018, this would leave you to the mongos> prompt.
2. Give the following command.

> ```
>    mongos> sh.enableSharding("sharddb");
>     { "ok" : 1 }
> ```

this command tells mongodb that the database "sharddb" is enable for sharding.

3. Now specify the collection and the key which needs to be sharded.

> ```
> > mongos> sh.shardCollection("sharddb.neighbourhoods",{"_id":1},true) 
> > {"collectionsharded" : "sharddb.neighbourhoods", "ok" : 1 }
> ```

Once you have specified all the details, do the below mongoimport command via the command prompt

```
> C:\Users\yc03ak1>mongoimport --db sharddb --collection
> "neighbourhoods" --drop --type json  --host "localhost:47018"  --file
> "c:\Users\yc03ak1\Desktop\neighborhoods.json"

> 2016-08-14T15:32:03.087-0700    connected to: localhost:47018
> 2016-08-14T15:32:03.091-0700    dropping: sharddb.neighbourhoods
> 2016-08-14T15:32:04.743-0700    imported 195 documents
```

this would create the documents in the collection neighbourhoods in the sharddb as sharded collections.

you can check the sharded collections by

```
mongos> sh.status();
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("57a8f3d77ce8ef0f68a210c9")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "s0",  "host" : "s0/localhost:37017,localhost:37018,localhost:37019" }
        {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "s1/localhost:47018,localhost:47019" }
        {  "_id" : "s2",  "host" : "s2/localhost:57017,localhost:57018,localhost:57019" }
  active mongoses:
        "3.2.5" : 1
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
        Last reported error:  HostUnreachable
        Time of Reported error:  Thu Aug 11 2016 18:02:14 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "projects",  "primary" : "s1",  "partitioned" : true }
                projects.students
                        shard key: { "student_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                s0      1
                                s1      1
                                s2      1
                        { "student_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "student_id" : 1 } on : s2 Timestamp(3, 0)
                        { "student_id" : 1 } -->> { "student_id" : 25 } on : s1 Timestamp(3, 1)
                        { "student_id" : 25 } -->> { "student_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : s0 Timestamp(2, 0)
        {  "_id" : "test",  "primary" : "s2",  "partitioned" : true }
                test.zipcodes
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                s2      1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : s2 Timestamp(1, 0)
        {  "_id" : "sharddb",  "primary" : "s2",  "partitioned" : true }
                sharddb.neighbourhoods
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: true
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                s2      1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : s2 Timestamp(1, 0)

mongos>
```

HTH..

Comment: was i able to answer your doubts ? @user2307236